# Trivial Drive Build Fail

Tags: android, build

I have imported trivial drive and the build is failing..

Messages below..

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'C:\Users\Conner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aidl.exe' with arguments {-pC:\Users\Conner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\Conner\AndroidStudioProjects\TrivialDrive4\app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug -IC:\Users\Conner\AndroidStudioProjects\TrivialDrive4\app\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\Conner\AndroidStudioProjects\TrivialDrive4\app\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Users\Conner\AndroidStudioProjects\TrivialDrive4\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\aidl -IC:\Users\Conner\AndroidStudioProjects\TrivialDrive4\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.0.0\aidl -dC:\Users\Conner\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl2318381263201294414.d C:\Users\Conner\AndroidStudioProjects\TrivialDrive4\app\src\main\aidl\gersbach\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}

### App module gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.trivialdrivesample"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.5"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        // TODO(developer): uncomment below once config above is complete and uncommented.
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}

Not sure whats going on.  I have tried to used all build tools.. I have replaced my base64publickey with the one provided. And I have changed my 'com' package name.  I cannot generate an apk due to this build fail.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I had a similar issue. Turned out I had a spelling mistake in the package name.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the official guide (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-add-aidl) it tells you to copy-paste the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` into your project using Android Studio, however that won't work - it will be pasted into the wrong directory.

**Use your file browser** and copy-paste the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` into `<yourProject>/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/`. Then, rebuild the project and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

*have you set this permission?*

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

and have your aidl package under main package?